# Strange phenomenon in R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

Novice User here. I'm having a strange phenomenon where the indexing in one of my tables is jumping from 935 to 7491. I don't even have that many observations in my data. I have a table with 2500 observations and thats it. Furthermore, the indexing past 7491 seems to jump by ten's instead of 1's per row. Any light? Any reason?

[image]

Comment: Those are just row names. You can ignore them.

Comment: ...more precisely, their intended use is _not_ to simply count, one at a time, the number of rows in a data.frame or matrix. For instance, type `View(mtcars)`.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your current dataframe was subset from a previous dataframe that had more that 7500 rows.  When subsetting dataframes, rows keep their original row name.

Like joran says, its totally abritry, but if you really wanted to change it, try:

```
row.names(fold_1_test) <- seq(1, nrow(fold_1_test))
```

Comment: That seems super strange to me. The data is two files read from csv, each 1250 rows in size. then this fold_1_test matrix is created by stacking a submatrix from each of the 1250 matrices.

Comment: `fold_1_test <- rbind(positive_set[(4*n+1):(5*n), c('x1', 'x2', 'x3','x4','x5')], negative_set[(4*n+1):(5*n), c('x1', 'x2','x3','x4','x5') , drop = FALSE])`
  
  where n = 187